# Create Calculated Table in Power BI based on the earliest date that another criteria is met on

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a calculated table in Power BI that will provide one row per person based on the most earliest date that the score column is greater than 9. The initial table is thousands of rows and includes multiple entries per person if more than one score was collected.

Initial table:

[image: Initial Table]

Output goal:

[image]

Since Supergirl didn't ever have a score > 9, she isn't included in the output. Each person with a score > 9 will have one row with the score that occurred on the first date that the score was > 9 and the Date Completed.

I will then add columns and measures based on this new table. I tried using the summarize function and duplicating the initial table and manipulating it without success and have read many posts and didn't find anything that matched my ask. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

you could start off with creating an additional calculated column "TenOrMore" where you would simply calculate if Score >= 10 then true else false. Then your next select you can do max or min on the score where column "TenOrMore" is true or select all the values and calculate the next step. I hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to get it to mostly work adding a "TenOrMore" column to the original table. Below is my code:
index date = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(table1,
        table1[person]
        ),
        "Index Date", calculate(MIN(table1[date_completed]),
        table1[TenorMore]=1)
        ),
        table1[TenorMore]=1)

This creates a table with the person and minimum date I'm looking for, but I'm not able to display the actual score though. How can I add the score?

Comment: So that was step one. The next step you could add a row number or ordinal 1,2,3 and so on while ascending ordering the date and then simply select where row number is one. There should be a way to do all of this in one step and I will see if I can find any more info.

Comment: rankcolumn = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Score]),FILTER('Table','Table'[tenormore]=EARLIER('Table'[tenormore]))) - this should be created as a column and should give you minimum score for any score where tenormore was true, then try to select min datecompleted and min score and that should do it I hope